# Whether Camel Improves Performance?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

- I used simple java code to receive messages from ActiveMQ queues. It
  takes more than 1 hour to read 1000 messages from a queue.
- But now I used Apache camel for reading messages from ActiveMQ queue.
  It even does not take a single minute (52 seconds) to read 1000
  messages.
- I tried with the same messages for both programs.

My question is whether Camel improves the **performance** too?

Comment: Due to the non-blocking nature of Camel queues you process the message in parallel.

Comment: A bit hard to comment if you don't share the java and camel code.

Comment: Just ignore my case. Basically is there any variation in performance?

Comment: @mkbrv12  is it true?

Comment: Camel is written in Java. By definition, you can always write your own Java code with the same performance... The right question to ask, is whether writing a "good" (correct, performant...) implementation is easier with Camel than the alternatives. In your example, you probably made some very basic mistake in your simple implementation (1 hour to read 1000 messages sounds crazy slow - but we'd need to see the code to say more) and Camel apparently made it easy for you to avoid that mistake, so that's a win for Camel.

Comment: @mkbrv12 There's no such thing as "Camel queues", and Camel routes don't magically create parallelism - we'd need to see the code to say more. If the OP created a single route from a JMS queue, and used the default configuration for the JMS consumer, then the Camel version was single threaded (the `concurrentConsumers` option for the camel-jms component defaults to 1; the camel-activemq component should be the same since the documentation doesn't say otherwise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the performance variance is due to a problem in your Java client code. If you share a link to the source, might be able to identify the issue.

Comment: Just ignore my case. Basically is there any variation in performance?

Comment: No, there should be noticeable variation in performance. In general Camel should be easier to work with to _improve_ performance, b/c you can tweak configuration options (parallel consumers, connection/session/consumer caching) and other variables more readily to fit the use case.